# Need of explicit return in `then` for case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have a Sidekiq worker and in it using a case statement:

```
module Api
  def self.authenticate(company_id)
    Thread.current['api_company_id'] = company_id
    yield if block_given?
  ensure
    Thread.current['api_company_id'] = nil
  end
end

module Apis
  class PollTrackableJobWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    class EDocumentNotDoneError < StandardError; end
    class UnhandledCaseError < StandardError; end

    def perform(job_id, _invoice_id)
      Api.authenticate(1) do
        response = Api::TrackableJob.find(job_id).first

        case response['status']
        when 'done' then return true
        when 'error' then return handle_error(response['errors'])
        when 'pending' || 'running' then return raise EDocumentNotDoneError
        else raise UnhandledCaseError, response
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def handle_error(exception)
      Bugsnag.notify(exception) if defined?(Bugsnag)
    end
  end
end
```

`#perform` method is tested for all possible outcomes. Below, is a case for `done`:

```
class PollTrackableJobWorkerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'status is done' do
    response = {
      'type'       => 'trackable_jobs',
      'id'         => 'xxxxx',
      'status'     => 'done',
      'errors'     => nil
    }

    Api.expects(:authenticate).with(1).yields
    Api::TrackableJob.stubs(:find).with('xxxxx').returns([response])

    assert_equal(true, Apis::PollTrackableJobWorker.new.perform('xxxxx', 123))
  end
end
```

The test passes perfectly.

However, when I use implicit `return`, it keeps failing (returns `nil`).

For example, using a private method with an explicit `return` statement fails

```
case response['status']
when 'done' then returns_true
# code omitted
end

private

def returns_true
  return true
end
```

or using implicit `return` fails too

```
when 'done' then true
```

Why do I need explicit `return` for case statements?

Comment: "Why do I need explicit return for case statements?" - you don't. In fact, it's a bad practice. Unfortunately, you didn't provide enough code to let us reproduce the problem, so we can't say for sure what you are doing wrong. But you definitely do [something wrong].

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the feedback. I added the whole class.

Comment: That's better, but this  is not enough code to reproduce the problem (and too much irrelevant code). Please see this page: [mcve].

Comment: For example, all this sidekiq stuff is completely unrelated to the problem. You're not using any of it in the test anyway. But, in absence of explicit returns, result of that `perform` is whatever `Api.authenticate(1)` returns (which you didn't provide). That's why behaviour changes when you remove the returns.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev didn't think `Api.authenticate(1)` might be the reason until you mentioned it. Cleaned & updated the code! 

Comment: "Cleaned & updated the code!" -  aaaand now the problem does not reproduce (when running your code, not the test). I don't know minitest, but I think it's how you stub `Api.authenticate`. This way it returns nil always (because you didn't provide a return value when you stubbed it).